# Is there a better place on Stack Exchange for this question about a Perl+Tk RAM-related crash?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, site-recommendation

I donated now 250 points of mine to their question and with these "popping" bounties it will be the last. However, this user asks a good question and gets no answer. Is there a better place for it? Can we at least point them to some site they might find help?

[Perl Tk app sometimes crashes after exceeding 4GB ram usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73817378/13629335)

Comment: You donated more than 250 reputation, as that question has had, at least one other bounty offered on it.

Comment: @SecurityHound the bounty now has 200 and the one before 50, makes a total of 250 for me. :D

Comment: Afaik problem is that very few people is using perl tk. unix.stackexchange.com might worth a try.

Comment: The problem was in part that it simply didn't get in front of the eyes of the people who knew the answer. That happens sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fine where it is (in terms of sites on the network).

The bounty doesn't *guarantee* that an answer will come along, or that anyone will be able to answer the question, but it guarantees that the question gets improved visibility.

Realistically...the only thing one can do in this situation is to keep putting bounties on it in the hopes that enough attention is brought to the question such that someone is able to answer correctly.  Since you're not the OP, you could also invest a bit of time into trying to answer the question as well, but I could respect that's a bit time or domain-restrictive.

Comment: I don't know [tag:perl] and don't want to "waste" any more points on someone else issue, since I don't know when or if there come more [so] question I want to answer. I also don't know how many questions I will have in the future, so I'm keeping my points for now. Well I tried, thought there is a last thing I could do, but seems like I don't. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Thingamabobs:  If you are passionate about someone getting the help, then it's really not a "waste" to make the question more visible.  I can respect not wanting to continue to do that, though.  I also commiserate in not knowing Perl - was born a couple of generations too late, honestly - so I wouldn't be able to address the actual problem myself without any sense of expertise or confidence.  Sometimes this happens; experts aren't around to answer a question that an expert *should* be able to.

Comment: I'd guess the required expertise is more in the tk/tcl side of things.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I doubt that, but to be sure someone would need to write a GUI in non-tk and perl. Windows makes a distinction between "console" and "gui" applications. As else reported, on different platforms there is nothing wrong with the code. Therefore I had offered in the bounty that it is a language agnostic question. It would need a windows expert in my opinion.